# Index Match/Vlookup/Xlookup in List

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, vlookup

The way I setup the grid might void using Index/Match/Vlookup/XLookup but I am trying to scan the categories in columns `A thru O` looking for the correct date and fruit type in `row 1` from left to right. Then look at cost columns in `C, H, M` match the cost and return the amounts based on these inputs. The inputs are in yellow and the amount is the output/results.

Formula for cell `C19` thru `C22`:

`{=INDEX(A2:A16,E2:E16,F2:F16,J2:J16,K2:K16,O2:O16,MATCH(1,(A19=A1:O1)*(B19=C2:C16,H2:H16,M2:M16),0))}`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- How to use INDEX/MATCH

```
=INDEX($A$1:$O$16, MATCH($B19, $C$1:$C$16, 0), MATCH($A19, $A$1:$O$1, 0))
```

- How to use XLOOKUP

```
=XLOOKUP($B19, $C$1:$C$16, XLOOKUP($A19, $A$1:$O$1, $A$1:$O$16))
```

Those formulas will help you get the correct output/results.

Comment: What if columns `C,H,M` have different costs?

Comment: If so, try this.
IF(MATCH($A19, $A$1:$O$1, 0) <= 5, INDEX($A$1:$O$16, MATCH($B19, $C$1:$C$16, 0), MATCH($A19, $A$1:$O$1, 0)), IF(MATCH($A19, $A$1:$O$1, 0) <= 10, INDEX($A$1:$O$16, MATCH($B19, $H$1:$H$16, 0), MATCH($A19, $A$1:$O$1, 0)), INDEX($A$1:$O$16, MATCH($B19, $M$1:$M$16, 0), MATCH($A19, $A$1:$O$1, 0))))